# Scan and connect to Wifi networks using Java

Tags: java, network-programming, wifi, network-scan

Need to write a client, which can scan the available WIFI networks and connects to best known using Java. This might be desktop client which does this job. Any pointers would be helpful and appreciate your response.

Comment: I Don't understand your comment. Be nice.

Comment: No rudeness intended, only a mildly humorous joke. Java is a proper name, so when written only the `J` should be capitalized. Writing it as "JAVA", in online etiquette, would be shouting.

Comment: What's the deployment envrionment? Cross platform?

Comment: Do it in a native language if you cannot make do by invoking helper programs.

Answer (score 5):

You'll have to rely on a JNI library since you can't access a wireless device directly in Java.

[jWlanScan](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jwlanscan/) for Windows.

Comment: Thank you for the response. Let me try that one and see. Appreciate your quick help.

Comment: Unfortunately its not working on my 64 bit machiene. Is there any other API?

Comment: @user1686758 Sorry, I've got nothin. JNI components this specific are probably hard to come by, Java being OS/Hardware independent and all.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you to act upon your operating system. And for each of the supporting operating system try to analyse the results of the command lines needed to connect the wireless devices. It is quite straight forward and You will not have to work with JNI libraries.

For example for windows you can see the [ones introduced here](http://www.lovemytool.com/blog/2010/05/wifi-diagnostics-from-windows-7-or-vista-command-prompt-by-tony-fortunato.html), [here](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowToConnectToAWirelessWIFINetworkFromTheCommandLineInWindows7.aspx) and [here](http://www.nextofwindows.com/how-to-manage-a-wireless-wifi-network-from-the-command-line-in-windows-7/) and for the linux it is still easier.