# Connect java pc application to a mobile hotspot

Tags: java, network-programming, java-native-interface, wifi, android-wifi

> **Objective :** I want the java project to connect to a mobile(android) hotspot.

I referred to [WIFI - Scan and Connect using Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12517765/wifi-scan-and-connect-using-java) and tried using [jwlanSacn lib](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jwlanscan/?source=typ_redirect) but unfortunately it works only for 32 bit systems. This lib uses JNI.

> Is there a way to connect to a mobile hotspot in java? Any libraries ?
>   or can I create my own JNI code for it?

Also, referred to

[WIFI - Scan and Connect using Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12517765/wifi-scan-and-connect-using-java)

[Finding SSID of a wireless network with Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5378103/finding-ssid-of-a-wireless-network-with-java)

I'm working on 64bit Windows.

I'm new in pure java programming. Please help!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have to do it from the command line. You pretty much have to execute OS-specific instructions from your java program to command line using `Runtime.getRuntime().exec(...)` And then do some kind of parsing for the response you get. That's the idea.

Sorry I can't help more right now. I will update my answer as soon as I investigate this further