# JavaFX Raspberry WiFi searcher

Tags: javafx, raspberry-pi

I'm currently creating an application that will run on raspberry PI 3b+. I'd like to make "wifi searcher" inside an application. 
The wifi searcher would search the network and get networks data and than display me the wifi names and other wifi data that I'd need to display. Is this possible using JavaFX or do I need a plugin of some kind? How would I approach the problem? Can somebody give me some pointers?

Every search I do on "JavaFX wifi ..." or "JavaFx network ...." gives me no usable info on this topic.

I'd like it to look something like this:

[image: example of wifi searcher]

Comment: The first step is scanning for WiFi networks. According to [Scan and connect to WiFi networks using Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12517765/) and its linked questions, this isn't possible using pure Java—you'll need to use native code.

Comment: And you can also use the command line to scan the networks, like `sudo iwlist wlan0 scan`, using a `ProcessBuilder`, and then process the result.